# Get attribute value in html using xpath with xmllint

Tags: xpath, xmllint

Given an html document, I want to obtain for a set of attributes (that were already matched) their corresponding values using `xmllint` with an `xpath` expression. For example, retrieve the values of the `href` attributes values (not the whole attribute including its name) in `a` elements the get the links' urls.

I tried using `'//a/@href'` to get the attributes, but that gives me not just the values but also the attribute name. In some other posts it is said that you have to use the `string` function in this way `'string(//a/@href)'`, but when comparing both outputs I get different number of matches. For example:

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//a/@href' <(curl -L www.html-tidy.org) | wc
```

Gives:

```
HTML parser error : Tag nav invalid
    <nav><ul>
        ^
     50      50    2161
```

So there are 50 of them (the error comes from `xmllint` parsing html-tidy's web index).

When I use `string` function:

```
xmllint --html --xpath 'string(//a/@href)' <(curl -L www.html-tidy.org) | wc
```

It gives only one of the 50 matches.

```
    <nav><ul>
        ^
      1       1      26
```

so how can I use it properly (or which is the correct way of doing it)?
Thanks

Comment: `xmllint` is too low level for this, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Better use [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) for realLife©®™HTML. `xmllint` is good for well formatted HTML.

```
xidel -e '//a/@href' https://www.html-tidy.org
```

##### Output

```
https://github.com/htacg/html-tidy.org/tree/gh-pages/plus/_posts
https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/issues
https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/pulls
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Gettig attribute values can be done with `xmllint --html --recover --shell` and a lighweight post-processing despite the errors.
`xmllint --shell` receives commands from stdin

```
printf '%s\n' "cat //a/@href" "bye" |
    xmllint --html --recover --shell <(
        curl --silent -L www.html-tidy.org
    ) 2>/dev/null |
    cut --only-delimited -d '=' -f 2- | tr -d '"' | nl
```

Alternatives for extracting `href` value

```
<xmllint out> | grep 'href' | cut -d '=' -f2 | tr -d '"'
<xmllint out> | sed -rne '/href/ s/href="([^"]+)"/\1/p'
```

Result

```
 1   #homepage19700101htmltidy
 2   #homepage19700201what_is_tidy
 3   #homepage19700301documentation
 4   #homepage19700401history
 5   #homepage19700501acknowledgements
 6   #homepage19700601get_tidy
 7   #homepage19700701tidy_plus
 8   #homepage19700801freq
 9   http://www.htacg.org
10   https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/releases/tag/5.8.0
11   https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5
12   https://www.html-tidy.org/documentation/
13   https://www.html-tidy.org/developer/
14   http://api.html-tidy.org/
...
47   https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/issues
48   https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/pulls
49   https://www.htacg.org/
50   https://w3.org
```

Note: as with many Xpath 1.0 functions, `string([node set])` will operate only on first node of a node set.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out what happens with string function. So there no way to do this with `xmllint` alone (not using other programs such as `sed`, `awk` etc)?

Comment: No. I told you this is not the right tool. Trust me, I'm in this kind of things since more than a decade, as a daily basis. Check my github.